# serenity jbehave multiple browsers

Tags: testing, browser, automated-tests, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am trying to setup a test project that uses serenity and jbehave

I am noticing that all examples use serenity.properties that define a browser in it

I would like to structure my tests in a way so that same test can be executed in IE/firefox/chrome etc

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in properties as command line properties, so you can rerun the same tests with different browsers by passing in different settings for webdriver.driver, e.g.

```
$ mvn verify -Dwebdriver.driver=firefox
$ mvn verify -Dwebdriver.driver=chrome
```

etc.

Comment: I also need a single report, certainly I cannot be the only one to test an app in multiple browsers?

Comment: This feature may be supported in a future version of Serenity.

Comment: As a side comment, multi-browser testing isn't actually that common a requirement; many teams (particularly if they are using a UI framework with cross-browser support) prefer to focus on testing functionality rather then the browsers themselves.

Comment: really? how many teams gave you that data? every project I have worked in my 20 year career, the web apps NEED to be certified on certain browsers and version, which means dev/qa team is on the hook to test

Answer (score 0):

I think you are able to get this to work by creating multiple Junit test classes with each its own driver and execute them all in a single run.

Every test class should be able to assign a specific 'managed' driver (e.g. PhantomJS, Chrome, Firefox). This is documented here: http://www.thucydides.info/docs/serenity/#_serenity_webdriver_support_in_junit

I don't know what the impact this would have on the generated report, hopefully you are still able to identify the feature/driver combination.